# Swift -How to programmatically access collectionView's targetContentOffset.pointee.y

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

When a user swipes, I run some code in `scrollViewWillEndDragging` and I need the `targetContentOffset.pointee.y` to do it:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

    let yAxis = targetContentOffset.pointee.y

    let visibleItem = Int(yAxis / collectionView.frame.height)
    
    // do something with visibleItem based on cell's current vertical scroll position...
}
```

The issue is I also do some autoscrolling, where the user doesn't have to swipe and the cv auto scrolls. I still need access to the `targetContentOffset.pointee.y` so I can do something with with the visibleItem but I the method it's in doesn't trigger on autoscroll.

How can I programmatically access the targetContentOffset.pointee.y?

Comment: Ho do you auto scroll ?

Comment: It's vertical, full screen, I use this: `collectionView.scrollToItem(at:IndexPath(item: xyz, section: 0), at: .centeredVertically, animated: true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
let index = IndexPath(item: xyz, section: 0) 
collectionView.scrollToItem(at:index, at: .centeredVertically, animated: true)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
  if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at:index) {
    let frame = collectionView.convert(cell.frame,nil)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't need access to the cell, I need access to the the cell's frame/position inside the cv. WhenI use `let yAxis = targetContentOffset.pointee.y; let visibleItem = Int(yAxis / collectionView.frame.height)` I get it from there.